# Failed to open a session for a virtual machine Google Nexus

Tags: android, virtual-machine, genymotion

[I am getting the error as shown in the figure. I have gone through many such questions and answers but all in vain. Virutalbox version is 5.0.26 r108824 and genymotion version is 2.7.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGnES.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I had solved the error

Failed to create the VirtualBoxClient

Just go to your USER folder ie Document&settings or Your Username folder You will see the .virtualbox folder just click on that folder and remove the virtualbox.xml file and virtualbox.xml-prev file and again run the vbox it will automatically creates the above file and it will run perfect